# How do I get the string value of objMobileCapabilityDesc using a For loop?

Tags: java, android

I connect to a Web Service and pull down a JSON object.

My Class

```
public class UserLogin implements Serializable
{
    public int objMobileCapabilityId;
    public int objMobileCapabilityValue;
    public String objMobileCapabilityDesc;
    public int objMobileDisplayOrder;

    public UserLogin(){}

    public UserLogin(int objmobilecapabilityid, int objmobilecapabilityvalue, String objmobilecapabilitydesc, int objmobiledisplayorder) {

        objMobileCapabilityId = objmobilecapabilityid;
        objMobileCapabilityValue = objmobilecapabilityvalue;
        objMobileCapabilityDesc = objmobilecapabilitydesc;
        objMobileDisplayOrder = objmobiledisplayorder;
    }
}
```

I then take that data and create a UserLogin arraylist using TAGS

```
ArrayList<UserLogin> listofCapabilities = new ArrayList<UserLogin>();
try {
   // Invole web service
   androidHttpTransport.call(NAMESPACE+METHOD_NAME, envelope);
   // Get the response

        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        String responseJSON=response.toString();
        JSONArray jarray =new JSONArray(responseJSON);

        ACount = (jarray.length() -1);
        for (int i = 0; i <= ACount; i++) {

          Description = jarray.getJSONObject(i).getString(TAG_Description);
            if(Description.equals("Not a Valid Mobile User")){
                userOK = false;
            }else {
                userOK = true;
                objuserlogin.setProperty(2, Description);
                listofCapabilities.add(i, objuserlogin);
                objuserlogin = new UserLogin();
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I then pass the ArrayList to a second Activity

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
    if (userOK == true){
        Intent DisplayValidList = new Intent(MainActivity.this,  DisplayValidList.class);
        DisplayValidList.putExtra("Capabilities", listofCapabilities);
           startActivity(DisplayValidList);
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "You have entered an invalid User Name or Password. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

This is what I get in the second activity

```
ArrayList userCapabilities;
userCapabilities = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("Capabilities");

userCapabilities = {ArrayList@4448}  size = 2
 0 = {UserLogin@4458} 
  objMobileCapabilityDesc = "Test Rick"
  objMobileCapabilityId = 0
  objMobileCapabilityValue = 0
  objMobileDisplayOrder = 0
  shadow$_klass_ = {Class@4033} "class   rick.damselfly.com.traceall_mobile_app.UserLogin"
  shadow$_monitor_ = -1993118517
 1 = {UserLogin@4459} 
  objMobileCapabilityDesc = "Receive RM (Add/Edit/Delete)"
  objMobileCapabilityId = 0
  objMobileCapabilityValue = 0
  objMobileDisplayOrder = 0
  shadow$_klass_ = {Class@4033} "class rick.damselfly.com.traceall_mobile_app.UserLogin"
  shadow$_monitor_ = -2045944664
```

Sorry for the amount of code, didn't know the best way to discribe what I was trying to do. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post your JSON response data?

Comment: jarray = {JSONArray@4406} "[{"objMobileCapabilityId":2,"objMobileCapabilityValue":2,"objMobileCapabilityDesc":"Test Rick","objMobileDisplayOrder":2},{"objMobileCapabilityId":1,"objMobileCapabilityValue":1,"objMobileCapabilityDesc":"Receive RM (Add\/Edit\/Delete)","objMobileDisplayOrder":1}]"

Comment: That is invalid JSON can you paste exactly what responseJSON is?

Comment: This is what I am doing.

Comment: SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            String responseJSON=response.toString();
            JSONArray jarray =new JSONArray(responseJSON);

Comment: I guess what I am trying to do is, in Visual Studio you create an object, then assign items to that object name and then you can access that name anywhere in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so essentially you are just not creating your objects properly. Please take a look at the below.

So the first thing is with your class. Unless you define the variables in a different way you are not going to be able to retrieve those values. To make it easier for an example I just added some getters to your values.

```
public class UserLogin {

public int objMobileCapabilityId;
public int objMobileCapabilityValue;
public String objMobileCapabilityDesc;
public int objMobileDisplayOrder;

public UserLogin(){}

public UserLogin(int objmobilecapabilityid, int objmobilecapabilityvalue, String objmobilecapabilitydesc, int objmobiledisplayorder) {

    objMobileCapabilityId = objmobilecapabilityid;
    objMobileCapabilityValue = objmobilecapabilityvalue;
    objMobileCapabilityDesc = objmobilecapabilitydesc;
    objMobileDisplayOrder = objmobiledisplayorder;
}

public int getObjMobileCapabilityId() {
    return objMobileCapabilityId;
}

public int getObjMobileCapabilityValue() {
    return objMobileCapabilityValue;
}

public String getObjMobileCapabilityDesc() {
    return objMobileCapabilityDesc;
}

public int getObjMobileDisplayOrder() {
    return objMobileDisplayOrder;
}
}
```

Next and probably the bigger issue is the way you are retrieving and parsing your JSON to create new user objects. Below you can see how I did this. Essentially you can just create the JSON array and then in a for-loop you will create individual JSONObjects that you can then access to create your UserLogin objects. ALSO as you'll see I created a String to hold the JSON, this just would be your response string (I did this for ease of testing).

```
private void readYourJSON(){
    String jsonString = "[{\"objMobileCapabilityId\":2,\"objMobileCapabilityValue\":2,\"objMobileCapabilityDe\":\"Test Rick\",\"objMobileDisplayOrder\":2},{\"objMobileCapabilityId\":1,\"objMobileCapability\":1,\"objMobileCapabilityDesc\":\"Receive RM (Add\\/Edit\\/Delete)\",\"objMobileDisplayOrder\":1}]";
    ArrayList<UserLogin> users = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        Log.e("Size: ", String.valueOf(array.length()));
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
            JSONObject currentObject = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
            users.add(new UserLogin(currentObject.getInt("objMobileCapabilityId"),
                    currentObject.getInt("objMobileCapabilityValue"),
                    currentObject.getString("objMobileCapabilityDe"),
                    currentObject.getInt("objMobileDisplayOrder")
                    ));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    txt.setText(users.get(0).getObjMobileCapabilityDesc());
}
```

Now you can ignore the txt.setText at the bottom that is merely so I can show you the end result of the changes. I jammed the JSON parsing into a little method so clearly this is for example purposes and you will need to tailor it to really fit your needs. Also I highly recommend taking a look at the resources I have posted below to get you up to speed on things like this.

**End Result Example**

[image]

**Resources**

JSON - http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Objects: http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-objects-in-android/27048

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the response. I will definately look at those.

Comment: @RickS not a problem. If this helps please accept as answer.